# How can I assign a mutable object to a class member passing it as an argument of the __init__() function?

Tags: python, class, immutability

I want a python member variable to 'point' to another object, so that a member function can modify it. To do so, I am thinking of passing the object to be 'pointed' as an argument to the init, but I am not sure it can work, maybe because I find the python dichotomy between 'mutable' and 'unmutable' objects a bit confusing.

Comment: So, did you try and have any problem? Otherwise, what is your question exactly?

Comment: The *only* difference between mutable and immutable objects is that *immutable objects lack mutator methods*. There is no distinction, really, between the two different types of objects, as far as the semantics of the language goes, it is not a "dichotomy" really.

Comment: The same way you would handle an immutable object.

Comment: It worked, easier than expected. Thanks for the hints!